# Mysql how to get new date from a column date?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Hi I have a table that have timestamp column. I want to update a date with 1 second before of it. How can I do that?

> Exp: 
>  name | date 
>   ibrahim |
>   2011-04-14 03:35:05 
>  blabla |
>   2011-04-14 03:00:00 
> .
>  .
>  .

After update, date of second row should be "2011-04-14 02:59:59" etc.

edit:

answer is

> UPDATE table SET
>   date=DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 1 SECOND) 
>   WHERE name="blabla";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.

or

```
update `table` set date_date = date_date - INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set `date`= DATE_SUB(`date`,INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

**UPDATED**

To put the actual column name in query

**Side Note:** Your column name `date` is mysql reserved word so you have to put it in backticks `` otherwise mysql will produce syntax error as I did in above query.

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes.

Comment: @Raisen: Thanks, Good caught. Corrected

Comment: didnt work, I got that error "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'blabla' in 'field list'"

Comment: @ibrahim: Put your actual column name in place of blabla

Comment: @ibrahim: I just updated my answer to put actual column name just try it

Comment: @ibrahim: Good to know But you will be in the another problem very soon with the answer you posted